# Web API controller POST attempts a file download on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created an Web API controller in my MVC project.  Whenever I try to POST to this controller, it try's to initiate a File download, and I am not sure why.  It happens if I navigate to the API controller via URL or if it's done via a Form post.

It's a very simple scenario where an File is to be uploaded via a post.

Here is the controller code.  Any ideas?

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
    {

        public async Task<List<string>> Post()
        {
            // Verify that this is an HTML Form file upload request
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            // Create a stream provider for setting up output streams that saves the output under c:\tmp\uploads
            // If you want full control over how the stream is saved then derive from MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
            // and override what you need.
            MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("c:\\tmp\\");

             var task = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

            return new List<string>();
        }
```

Here is the client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Multiple File Upload Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/api/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    What is your name?
    <input name="submitter" size="40" type="text"><br>
    What files are you uploading?
    <input name="data" type=file multiple>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us how are you calling this controller action? I suspect that the problem is in your client code rather than the server.

Comment: Why are you returning a List<string>() ?

Comment: Will update with client code.  Returning a List<string> is just test code.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? if yes, the reponse could be coming back as `application/json`, in which case IE doesn't render it and shows a dialog like initiating file download. Did you try to open it and see. you should see Json representation of the response data.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you are using Internet Explorer to test this example, aren't you? But this browser always prompts for download when the server sends JSON (yeah IE sucks like hell, we all know that, please use a real web browser when you are doing web development). Your controller action returns JSON that IE is incapable of displaying inline and it asks you to save it on the client. I don't know what else did you expect? Your controller action returns an empty array as JSON. You have an HTML form to upload a file and the result of this file upload is an empty JSON array that IE doesn't know how to handle.

If you use an HTML client form you probably wanna return HTML from this API controller action, right?

Comment: Yes.  You were absolutely right.
The following corrections made it work the way I intended.  -> public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()  -> return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

Comment: As a REST controller, it's probably not a good idea to be returning HTML from the controller action.  Agreed?  What would your approach be? (FYI, this is my very first WebAPI/MVC code)